# Magento 2 - Show Subcategories and Images on Category Template

Tags: magento2, template, category-products

I want to show subcategories and the images on the category page.  If the user clicks on Apparel the page would show all the subcategories with the subcategory image.

I placed this code in my theme in My/theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/category/products.phtml

```
<?php
    $category = $block->getCurrentCategory();
    $subcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>

    <?php if(count($subcategories) > 0): ?>
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid">
            <ol class="products list items product-items">
                <?php foreach($category->getChildrenCategories() as $subcategory): ?>
                    <?php $subcategory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($subcategory->getId()); ?>
                    <li class="item product product-item m6-category">
                        <div class="product-item-info">
                          <div class="m6-cat-image">
                            <?php if ($_imgUrl = $subcategory->getImageUrl()): ?>
                                <a href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                                    <span class="product-image-container">
                                        <?php $_imgHtml = '<img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" />'; ?>
                                        <?php echo $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($subcategory, $_imgHtml, 'image'); ?>
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                          </div>
                          <div class="product details product-item-details">
                              <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                                  <a class="product-item-link" href="<?= $subcategory->getUrl() ?>"><?= $subcategory->getName() ?></a>
                              </strong>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ol>
        </div>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php if (!$block->isContentMode() || $block->isMixedMode()): ?>
            <?= $block->getProductListHtml() ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

For some reason it doesn't show all the subcategories of the main category.  For example, if I have main category of Apparel and subs of Shirts, Pants and Shoes only Shirts and Pants show even though all the category settings are the same.  I think this must be something with the categories we created and not the code above.  But I just wanted to ask.

Also, I know you are not supposed to use objectManager so is there a way to do this in this template without building a module?

Thanks, Stan